# custom (private) URL in message body of a twilio whatsapp message

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-php

I can successfully send a message to my whatsapp using both the curl (bash) and python methods using the code here: https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/learn

However if I change the standard template body URL from yummycupcakes.com to a private IP (10.0.0.x), the message fails.  Logs show:

*Error:   63030 Unsupported parameter for type of channels message*

*Description:   Unsupported parameter for type of channels message*

Is it really trying to resolve links in my message body, and refusing to send the messageif it is un-resolvable?  Very restrictive if so.  Not clear if this is a twilio limitation or whatsapp...

Anyone with ideas here?
Example code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client 

account_sid = '<my_sid>' 
auth_token = '<my_authtoken>' 
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 

message = client.messages.create( 
                              from_='whatsapp:+<my#>',  
                              body='Your Yummy Cupcakes Company order of 1 dozen frosted cupcakes has shipped and should be delivered on July 10, 2019. Details: http://www.yummycupcakes.com/',      
                              to='whatsapp:+<my#>' 
                          ) 

print(message.sid)
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: It's the exact code in the link above, with the URL changed from yummycupcakes.com to 10.0.0.22.  And my custom SID/auth token.  Will copy/paste that above.

Comment: I SUSPECT(?) that twilio is forcing the preview_url option in their whatsapp API interface and failing because of that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/text#urls

Comment: It's the exact code in the link above, with the URL changed from yummycupcakes.com to 10.0.0.22.  And my custom SID/auth token.  Will copy/paste that above. Note that if I change the yummycupcakes.com URL to google.com or any other public URL, it is successful.

Comment: You say that you are just changing the URL to an IP? I am not getting an error. It just doesn't render it as a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code and did not get the error you encountered. It just does not render it as a clickable URL. Let me know if our code differs on something.

```
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
message = client.messages.create(
                              from_='whatsapp:+number',
                              body='Your Yummy Cupcakes Company order of 1 dozen frosted cupcakes has shipped and should be delivered on July 10, 2019. Details: http://{}'.format("10.0.0.22"),
                              to='whatsapp:+number'
                          )
print(message.sid)
```

Comment: Interesting.  Doesn't work at all for me.  Same error!  I think the core of the bug is the fact that whatsapp's preview_url is enabled by the twilio api call.  It says in the whatsapp doc that IP's aren't allowed.  If your IP was interpreted as an IP (and not text), it would hopefully fail also.  I filed an issue on github: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/issues/505

Comment: I believe because your code is not rendering as a clickable URL, it's not attempting to load the preview and therefore not failing.  Having a clickable URL is the goal here as copy/paste on mobile is not friendly user behavior.

Comment: Closed since it's not a library issue, but twilio issue.  If anyone has support on twilio, a ticket for this would be helpful. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/issues/505#event-2980030935